# Getting wrong orientation

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiinterfaceorientation

I am having an issue in my application which drives me mad. In my application, I rotate the simulator to the landscape mode, but in my below function, I get portrait orientation.

What is the problem here? Please help me out.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
  if ( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || 
  interfaceOrientation ==    UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown )
  {
    NSLog(@" portrait orientation");
  }
  else
  {
    NSLog(@"Landscape"); 
  }
 return YES;
}
```

Comment: Please update the sdk and xcode version you are using. As when I run the same code I get the expected result. Probably your xcode has some issues.

Answer (score 1):

First set the orientation value is the method

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Overriden to allow any orientation.
NSLog(@"shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation called...");
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
        defaultOrientation = 0;
    else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        defaultOrientation = 1;
    [self setTheOrientation];
    return YES;
```

}

Now set the values of the coordinates which you require according to the boolean values in the setTheOrientation method.

Answer (score 1):

The method returns BOOL, you have to return either YES or NO

Comment: sorry ..that was a typo..what i am asking is my simulator is in landscape mode but i get the portrait orientation is printed..any help

Comment: really interesting, I don't understand why, did you try debug and see what is printed out in interfaceOrientation?

Comment: You may try with NSLog(@"%d", interfaceOrientation);

Comment: Hi..actually i rotate the simulator to landscape but when i see the debug statement it shows that "Portrait" mode...this is my issue..any helps?

Comment: did you test on device? did you nslog the interfaceOrientation

Answer (score 0):

Why you did't return a BOOL value? YES or NO to tell the OS that you're gonna handle corresponding orientation events.

Answer (score 0):

If you want portrait mode then add return TRUE in *if clouse* and If you want landscape then add return TRUE in *else clouse* and if you want both mode then just type return TRUE in shouldAutoRotate clouse