# UIDevice Orientation not returning the correct value

Tags: iphone

Hey this is the code I am using

```
switch ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]) 

        {
            case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
                [self displayActionSheetInPotraitMode];
                break;
            case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
                [self displayActionSheetInLandscapeMode];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
```

but when I try it in iOS version 4 or 4.1 on the device

switch ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])

doesn't return the proper value. My application is to run in IOS 4 onwards. How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this

[Getting wrong orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560545/help-getting-wrong-orientation/4560614#4560614)

or else try

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
```

and then

```
switch(orientation)
```

Cheers